# How to get PHP script to display list content by category type

Tags: php

For my first php effort can to input and display addresses and descriptions of available housing . Now trying to break out/display by housing category type, i.e. House, Apt, Duplex, Condo.  All info is in same table. I have a row called Category, with corresponding values of 1, 2, 3, 4, that I hope to use as the category types.
I'm struggling with the manual and would appreciate any guidance.
Many thanks for your time and assistance.

Below is what I'm currently using to display the entire list.

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td valign=\"top\" class='address' width=\"180\" colspan=\"3\">".$res['address']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo  "<tr>";
    echo "<td valign=\"top\"  class='text_box' width=\"420\" colspan=\"3\">".$res['desc1']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo  "<tr>";
    echo "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\"  class='text_box' width=\"100\">".$res['bds']."</td>";
    echo "<td valign=\"top\"  align=\"left\" class='text_box' width=\"100\">".$res['bath']."</td>";
    echo "<td valign=\"top\"  align=\"left\" class='text_box' width=\"412\"></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: can you please add your sql query.  It can be done with that.

Comment: thank you..I should have known to include this - $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties ORDER BY id DESC");

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but would it not be possible to order your rows by category when you're making the MySQL-call? 'order by category' or whatever your column name is.

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-sql-tutorial/